# Rails doesn't handle params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement advanced search.

I have this in the model:

```
def self.filter(params)
params.inject(self) do |scope, (key, value)|
  return scope if value.blank?
  case key
    when :min_size
      scope.scoped(:conditions => ["size >= ?", value])
    when :max_size
      scope.scoped(:conditions => ["size <= ?", value])
    else
      scope.scoped(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", 4.weeks.ago]) 
  end
end
end
```

This is in my controller:

```
  def search
    @listings = Listing.filter(params)
    respond_to (:html)
  end
```

and I search with this form:

```
<%= form_tag '/search', :method => "get" do |f|  %>
    <%= text_field_tag :min_size, params[:min_size] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :max_size, params[:max_size] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

When I'm trying to search Rails seems to ignore all the params passed and finds all the entries with the last case switch ("created_at > ?", 4.weeks.ago). Params, however, do pass:

```
 Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&min_rent=10&max_rent=35" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Jan 31 12:25:40 +0500 2011
 Processing by ListingsController#search as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "min_size"=>"40", "max_size"=>"50"}
 Listing Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (created_at > '2011-01-03 07:25:40.978742') AND (created_at > '2011-01-03 07:25:40.980977') AND (created_at > '2011-01-03 07:25:40.982080') AND (created_at > '2011-01-03 07:25:40.983077') AND (created_at > '2011-01-03 07:25:40.984138')
```

What might be the problem here? In console it works just fine

```
>> some = Listing.filter(:min_size => 40, :max_size => 50)
=> [#<Listing id: 1, title: "1 br apartment, Paris 16e", address: "1 Rue Monsieur-le-Prince", district: "Paris 6e", size: 42, rent: 2000, created_at: "2011-01-26 18:30:57", updated_at: "2011-01-26 19:00:44">]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is switch-case comparison:

```
case key
```

I think from the inject the key is "min_size" not :min_size and that's why it always goes to else branch.

EDIT:

Try changing the code as

```
when "min_size"
  scope.scoped(:conditions => ["size >= ?", value])
when "max_size"
  scope.scoped(:conditions => ["size <= ?", value])
```

and it should work. Maybe :)

Comment: @Ghinzu, I'm glad to hear! Hear at StackOverflow you thank the best by accepting the answer that worked for you.

Comment: From SO faq: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community."

Comment: +1 for a good answer. I love it when they are clear and concise like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the Searchlogic gem.

with Searchlogic you can do a greater than/less than search like this:

```
irb> Listing.search(:size_gt => 10, :size_lt => 100)
```

in your controller:

```
def index
  @search = Listing.search(params[:search])
end
```

in your view:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f|  %>
  <%= f.text_field :size_gt %>
  <%= f.text_field :size_lt %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

urls look like this

```
/listings?search[size_gt]=10&search[size_lt]=100
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I will probably use that gem, but I still would like to find out what's wrong with my code :-)